# lwIP UDP messaging - receiver stops working after PBUF_POOL_SIZE times yet pbuf's ARE being freed

Tags: udp, stm32f4, lwip

I am using lwIP on an STM32 chip to implement UDP echo. (I copied much of the code from the DHCP module which seems to be working perfectly.) I have a simple Python script as the ECHO server.

I am running in NO_SYS mode - everything is called from the main loop.

Everything works perfectly for the first N times, after which the request is sent, the server responds (I see this in wireshark) - but the received packet simply does not get picked up by lwIP.

N can be reliably changed by changing the config variable PBUF_POOL_SIZE, so you might think that pbuf's are not being freed after use, so the pool runs out. But that does not seem to be the case.

The implementation I am using (like that of DHCP) is that the same pcb and pbuf pair are used both to send and receive. The code looks like this:

```
   
typedef enum SIGNAL_STATE {
    SIGNAL_STATE_IDLE,          // 0
    SIGNAL_STATE_WAIT_ACK,      // 1
} SIGNAL_STATE;

void send_app_broadcast_msg(char *msg);
static void app_inc_pcb_refcount(void);
static void app_dec_pcb_refcount(void);
void rcv_app_msg(void *arg, struct udp_pcb *pcb, struct pbuf *p,
        const ip_addr_t *addr, u16_t port);

SIGNAL_STATE signal_state = SIGNAL_STATE_IDLE;

// allocation and ref counting, copied from DHCP code
static struct udp_pcb *pcb_out = NULL;
struct pbuf *p_out = NULL;
static u8_t app_pcb_refcount = 0;
static char *msg = "MSG #17";
static uint32_t rx_flag = 0;
static uint32_t timeout_ctr = 0;

void app_send_signal(void)
{
    // send "button" was pressed, what to do?
    switch (signal_state) {
    case SIGNAL_STATE_IDLE :
        rx_flag = 0;
        send_app_broadcast_msg(msg);
        signal_state = SIGNAL_STATE_WAIT_ACK;
        break;
    case SIGNAL_STATE_WAIT_ACK:
        // double press, ignore
        break;
    default:
        // illegal state, fatal error!
        fatal_error("%s : Illegal State: %d\n", __func__, signal_state);
        break;
    }
}

void app_check_timeouts(void){
    // this is called every half second by the main loop
    uint8_t c = 0;
    uint32_t end_flag = 0;
    // handle msg response and timeout
    switch (signal_state) {
        case SIGNAL_STATE_IDLE :
        // do nothing
            break;
        case SIGNAL_STATE_WAIT_ACK:
            timeout_ctr++;
            if (rx_flag){
                xprintf("OK\n");
                end_flag = 1;
            } else if ( timeout_ctr > PIXEE_TIMEOUT ) {
                xprintf("TIMED OUT\n");
                end_flag = 1;
            }
            if (end_flag)
            {
                c = pbuf_free(p_out);
                xprintf("p_out=%d ref=%d, c=%d\n", p_out, p_out->ref, c);
                app_dec_pcb_refcount();
                p_out = NULL;
                pcb_out = NULL;
                timeout_ctr = 0;
                rx_flag = 0;
                signal_state = SIGNAL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            break;
        default:
            // illegal state, fatal error!
            fatal_error("%s : Illegal State: %d\n", __func__, signal_state);
            break;
    }
}

void send_app_broadcast_msg(char *msg)
{
    uint32_t sz = strlen(msg);
    if ( sz > APP_MAX_MSG_SIZE )
    {
        fatal_error("%s : requested message too large (%d, %d) \n", __func__, sz, APP_MAX_MSG_SIZE);
    }

    xprintf("sending broadcast msg \"%s\"... ", msg);
    pixee_inc_pcb_refcount();
    if ( pcb_out == NULL )
    {
        fatal_error("%s : could not allocate out pcb\n", __func__);
    }
    ip_set_option(pcb_out, SOF_BROADCAST);
    udp_bind(pcb_out, IP4_ADDR_ANY, APP_PORT_NUM);
    udp_connect(pcb_out, IP4_ADDR_ANY, APP_PORT_NUM);
    udp_recv(pcb_out, rcv_app_msg, NULL);

    p_out = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, sz, PBUF_RAM);
    if ( p_out == NULL )
    {
        fatal_error("%s : could not allocate out pbuf of %d\n", __func__, sz);
    }
    p_out->payload = msg;

    udp_sendto(pcb_out, p_out, IP_ADDR_BROADCAST, APP_PORT_NUM);
}


static void app_inc_pcb_refcount(void)
{
  if (app_pcb_refcount == 0) {
      if ( pcb_out != NULL )
      {
          fatal_error( "%s : memory leak\n", __func__ );
      }


    pcb_out = udp_new();

    if (pcb_out == NULL)
    {
        fatal_error( "%s : could not allocate pcb\n", __func__ );
    }

    udp_bind(pcb_out, IP4_ADDR_ANY, APP_PORT_NUM);
    udp_connect(pcb_out, IP4_ADDR_ANY, APP_PORT_NUM);
    udp_recv(pcb_out, rcv_app_msg, NULL);
  }

  pixee_pcb_refcount++;

  return;
}

static void app_dec_pcb_refcount(void)
{
    if (!(app_pcb_refcount > 0))
    {
        fatal_error( "%s : refcount error\n", __func__ );
    }

  app_pcb_refcount--;

  if (app_pcb_refcount == 0) {
    udp_remove(pcb_out);
    pcb_out = NULL;
  }
}


void rcv_app_msg(void *arg, struct udp_pcb *pcb, struct pbuf *p,
        const ip_addr_t *addr, u16_t port)
{
    // callback from the ISR
    rx_flag = 1;
}
```

How do I know the same pbuf keeps getting reused? Here is the console output from xprintf():

```
sending broadcast msg "MSG #17"... OK                                   
p_out=536900484 ref=0, c=1                                                      
sending broadcast msg "MSG #17"... OK                                   
p_out=536900484 ref=0, c=1                                                      
sending broadcast msg "MSG #17"... OK                                   
p_out=536900484 ref=0, c=1                                                      
sending broadcast msg "MSG #17"... OK                                   
p_out=536900484 ref=0, c=1                                                      
sending broadcast msg "MSG #17"... OK                                   
p_out=536900484 ref=0, c=1                                                      
sending broadcast msg "MSG #17"... TIMED OUT                            
p_out=536900484 ref=0, c=1
```

On this pass, PBUF_POOL_SIZE = 5. If I change it to 8, I'll get 8 good runs then a timeout. As you can see, "c" is the number of pbuf's freed which is always 1, and the pointer to the pbuf is the same each call. So it looks as if the same pbuf is reused over and over.

(For the record I've also tried a version with separate pcb's and pbuf's for send and received - I couldn't get that to receive at all.)

Any ideas?